# Can't get ng2-charts to show up in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to use ng2-charts (http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) to display a line graph.

There isn't much of a tutorial on the site - I've followed the installation steps and am currently looking at the Markup and TypeScript they've included for the line graph section. I've cut and paste their code into mine and nothing is showing up whatsoever. Does anyone here have experience with ng2-charts - if so can you point me in the right direction?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <base-chart class="chart"
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColours"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
            <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button (click)="randomize()">CLICK</button>
</div>
```

And here's my TypeScript file:

```
    import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Routes} from '../routes.config';
import {ATRService} from '../atr/atr.service';
import {AtrConfiguration} from '../atrConfiguration/atrConfiguration.model';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';


declare var Chart: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './app/home/home.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS, ATRService
    ]
})
export class Home {
    public sensors: Array<string> = [];
    public selectedSensor: string = null;

    public atrConfigs: Array<AtrConfiguration> = [];
    public selectedConfiguration: string = null;

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _atrService: ATRService) {

        this.getSensors()
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.sensors = res;
            });

        _atrService.getConfigurations()
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.atrConfigs = res;
            });
    }

    getSensors() {
        //return an observable
        console.log('Home:getSensors entered...');

        return this._http.get('/atr/sensors')
            .map((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            });
    }






    // lineChart
    public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
        { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' },
        { data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C' }
    ];
    public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
    public lineChartOptions: any = {
        animation: false,
        responsive: true
    };
    public lineChartColours: Array<any> = [
        { // grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
        },
        { // dark grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
        },
        { // grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
        }
    ];
    public lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
    public lineChartType: string = 'line';

    public randomize(): void {
        let _lineChartData: Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
            _lineChartData[i] = { data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label };
            for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
                _lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            }
        }
        this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
    }

    // events
    public chartClicked(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }

    public chartHovered(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Edit: I just inspected Chrome's developer tools and I'm getting these errors:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Can't bind to 'ngForLabel' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Property binding ngForLabel not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 35 in [ngFor let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index] in Home@20:20 ("
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
"): Home@20:20
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Can't bind to 'ngForD' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
Property binding ngForD not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
browser_adapter.js:76EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Can't bind to 'ngForLabel' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Property binding ngForLabel not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 35 in [ngFor let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index] in Home@20:20 ("
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
"): Home@20:20
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Can't bind to 'ngForD' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
Property binding ngForD not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:86ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:56(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193schedulerFn @ async.js:122SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:111NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:310Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:218drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:469ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:408
browser_adapter.js:76STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:58(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193schedulerFn @ async.js:122SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:111NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:310Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:218drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:469ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:408
browser_adapter.js:76Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Can't bind to 'ngForLabel' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Property binding ngForLabel not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 35 in [ngFor let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index] in Home@20:20 ("
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
"): Home@20:20
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Can't bind to 'ngForD' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
Property binding ngForD not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:517)
    at zone.js:494
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:306)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:44)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:305)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:201)
    at zone.js:550
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:339)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:35)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:338)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:59(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193schedulerFn @ async.js:122SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:111NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:310Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:218drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:469ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:408
zone.js:443Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Can't bind to 'ngForLabel' since it isn't a known native property ("      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of line"): Home@17:20
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Property binding ngForLabel not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
                [ERROR ->]<th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of "): Home@17:16
Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 35 in [ngFor let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index] in Home@20:20 ("
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
"): Home@20:20
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Can't bind to 'ngForD' since it isn't a known native property ("                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=ind"): Home@19:16
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12
Property binding ngForD not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
                <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
            </tr>
            [ERROR ->]<tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'ngFor' since…let label of lineChartLabels; let j"): Home@19:12", stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'ngFor…(http://localhost:5000/vendor.bundle.js:14518:42)"}
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308611/angular2-parser-error-unexpected-token/37308853#answer-37308853

Comment: Thanks. That clears up the errors. Also for anyone interested, I just found out that ng2-charts requires a different version Angular 2 (RC.1) from the one I'm currently using which is most likely the issue with the charts not showing up.

Comment: You might be interested in PrimeNG Charts.js implementation that uses latest charts.js with full access to charts.js api. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart